# Algorithm for consecutive n-head

Tags: javascript, algorithm, statistics

I have to tackle this statistics problem for my current project: Given a series of coin flips, calculate the percentage of consecutive n-heads runs. The data is bellow, 1 for head and 0 for tail. I found [this reference](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~ginsparg/physics/INFO295/mh.pdf) about the probability of n-heads and have no clue of how to apply that to deride an algorithm (javascript prefered). I would appreciate any hints. Thanks!

flips = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0. 0];

Edit:

1. The coin is not a fair coin so the next outcome of the flip would only be based on the history. For example, I don't see any 3-tails run (3 zeroes in a row) in the history so the chance of next outcome is probably 0%.
2. So, this is my interpretation of the **percentage of consecutive n-heads runs** is what is probability of the outcome of next flip. :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "the percentage of consecutive n-head runs"?

Comment: Did you mean: "How often does the coin flip result change in relation to the number of flips"?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please read again to see if I made any sense. :)

Comment: It sounds like you are overthinking this.  First you need to write a loop to generate an array of lengths of runs, *then* do statistics.  So the above would generate an array of `[4, 1, 2]` and your answer would be `4/7` of the runs have length `1`, `1/7` have length `2` and `2/7` have length `3`.